# Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, post, método

tengo un problema con un formulario, envio las variables por post y guarda in problemas, pero me arroja un aviso
Notice: Undefined index: despues in C:\wamp64\www\modelo\editar_productos2.php on line 47 y no se que puede estar mal

```
<form action="" method="post">
                        <table border="1" align="center" id='usuarios' cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Producto</th>
                                <th>Cantidad</th>
                                <th>Ingreso</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class='item2'>

                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="cajas" value="<?php echo $row->nombre; ?>" disabled>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" class="cajas" value="<?php echo $row->existencia; ?>" disabled> 
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="number" id="despues" class="cajas" value="0" name="despues" onchange="return validanumero(this)" required>
                                </td>
                        </table>
                        </br></br>
                        <input type="submit" class="boton" name="submit" value="Aceptar">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input id="boton" class="boton" type="button" value="Cancelar" onclick="window.location = '../vista/administracion_productos.php'">
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    $antes = $row->existencia;
                    $var = $_POST['despues'];
                    $total = $antes+$var;
                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $field = array("existencia" => $total);
                        $tbl = "productos";
                        edit($tbl, $field, 'id_prod', $id);
                        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='../vista/administracion_productos.php'</script>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
```

El codigo de l pagina que registra el cambio en la bd

```
function edit($tblname, $form_data, $field_id, $id) {
$sql = "UPDATE " . $tblname . " SET ";
$data = array();

foreach ($form_data as $column => $value) {

    $data[] = $column . "=" . "'" . $value . "'";
}
$sql .= implode(',', $data);
$sql .= " where " . $field_id . " = '" . $id . "'";
return db_query($sql);
}
```

en la linea 47 es donde asigno el campo a una variable para operarla

```
$var = $_POST['despues'];
```

Muchas gracias por su colaboracion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema es que estas intentando usar el indice "despues" en la variable $_POST el cual sin hacer el envío de los datos no existe. hay varias formas de solucionar el problema, la mas sencilla es comprobar si la variable existe para usarla con la funcion isset.

```
$var = (isset($_POST['despues']) ? $_POST['despues'] : 0);
```

En tu caso podrías mover la linea a lka sección dentro de la condicion if que comprueba que se ha enviado el formulario, tu código quedaría asi:

```
<?php

                    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $antes = $row->existencia;
                    $var = $_POST['despues']; // ESTA LINEA LA MOVÍ
                    $total = $antes+$var;     // ESTA LINEA LA MOVÍ
                        $field = array("existencia" => $total);
                        $tbl = "productos";
                        edit($tbl, $field, 'id_prod', $id);
                        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='../vista/administracion_productos.php'</script>";
                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracia, solucionado el problema