# Usar Variables con la posibilidad de ser indefinidas sin tener errores en PHP

Tags: php, variables

Tengo un formulario donde **a veces aparece un campo y otras veces no**, y desde la validación con PHP necesito **almacenar todos los valores** de los campos **en variables**.

Entonces, no puedo hacer esto porque aparecería un error:

```
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
```

Pero tampoco quiero hacer esto porque son muchos los campos y me gustaría hacerlo de una forma más eficiente si es posible:

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
}
```

¿Hay alguna alternativa que por ejemplo deje la variable con NULL (por ejemplo) si el campo no existe y de una forma más eficiente?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Notice: Undefined index](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139935/notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para estos casos yo uso un operador ternario, verificando el POST con `empty`.

```
$nombre = !empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
/*
   En lo adelante usaremos $nombre para todo lo que haga falta
   $nombre será igual a lo que haya en el POST, 
   o NULL si no hay clave 'nombre' en el POST
*/
```

---

#### Otra posibilidad

Si quieres evitar muchas comprobaciones, otra cosa que puedes hacer es enviar un objeto ordenado desde el cliente, donde dentro del objeto global, pones un objeto anidado con los valores requeridos.

Imaginemos un escenario donde, para que se ejecute una determinada acción en el servidor es obligatorio que en el POST vengan datos para `nombre, apellido, direccion, edad`.

Suponiendo que estamos usando Ajax, que sería lo más común, puedes pasar al servidor un objeto así:

```
{
    required: {
        nombre: 'Pedro',
        apellido: 'Guerrero',
        direccion: 'Calle 1 ...',
        edad: 20
    },
    cargo: 'Supervisor',
    salario: 10000      
}
```

En el servidor, se haría una comprobación simple, basada en verificar si en el POST hay una clave `required` o no:

```
$mainData=!empty($_POST['required']) ? $_POST['required'] : NULL;
if ($mainData){
    /*
       Nótese que aquí ya no usamos $_POST, sino $mainData
       Se asume que del lado del cliente hay controles 
       para que ninguno de estos datos pase en blanco
       de todos modos, podemos usar un ternario si queremos
    */
    $nombre=  !empty($mainData['nombre'])   ? $mainData['nombre']   : '';
    $apellido=!empty($mainData['apellido']) ? $mainData['apellido'] : '';
    //... etc y ejecutar acción

} else {
    //... No hacer nada e informar de que no estaban los datos requeridos
}
```

Esto es una posibilidad, si se quieren evitar comprobaciones largas del tipo `if ($dato1 && $dato2 && dato99) {` en el caso de que haya muchos datos obligatorios. Subrayando de nuevo que en el cliente debe haber un control estricto para que ninguno de esos datos pase vacío.

Answer (score 6):

También si estas usando PHP 7 o posterior puedes usar el *NULL COALESCENCE OPERATOR* así

```
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'] ?? NULL;

echo $nombre;
```

Cito

> El operador de fusión de null (??) se ha añadido como aliciente sintáctico para el caso común de la necesidad de utilizar un operador ternario junto con isset(). Devuelve su primer operando si existe y no es NULL; de lo contrario devuelve su segundo operando.

[Referencia del operador](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

Answer (score 2):

Una forma rápida es utilizar el operador de control de errores, el signo de arroba (@) que suprime el mensaje de error que pueda generarse al buscar una llave no definida.

```
$nombre = @$_POST['nombre'];
```

Las advertencias tienen la finalidad de orientar al desarrollador en la corrección de errores y aunque el operador @ evita que el aviso se imprima en la pantalla el error aún existe. Ignorar las advertencias es mal visto ya que significa que sabes que tu código tiene errores y que no te importa corregirlos.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tengo que hacer un mockup de un webhook uso esta técnica:

- un array con campos permitidos
- de los que vienen filtro los que son válidos
- calculo los que no están
- armo un array final con los valores de los campos válidos y del resto en null o vacío

---

```
<?php
// campos permitidos
$allowedFields = [
  'email',
  'areacode',
  'phone',
  'firstname',
  'lastname',
  'address',
  'city',
  'state',
  'zip',
  'company',
];

$finalData = [];

// cambiamos el case a los get post y cookies recibidos ( aquí podes limitar a post )
$inputData = array_change_key_case( $_REQUEST );

// intersectamos los campos permitidos contra los campos recibidos, 
// para obtener los campos válidos
$validKeys = array_intersect( array_unique( $allowedFields ), array_keys( $inputData ) );

// calculamos la diferencia entre los campos permitidos y los campos recibidos,
// para obtener los campos que faltan ( los que iran undefined )
$testKeys = array_diff( array_unique( $allowedFields ), array_keys( $inputData ) );

// por cada campo válido tomar el valor
foreach ($validKeys as $key) :
  $finalData[$key] = $inputData[$key];
endforeach;

// por cada campo que falta ponerlo como vacío, null o "undefined"
foreach ($testKeys as $key) :
  $finalData[$key] = '';
endforeach;

var_dump( $finalData );
```