# ¿Saber si un elemento de un array existe en otro array PHP?

Tags: php, array

En el registro de cada persona del listado, es preciso que el sistema evalúe
si el nombre del color existe en un segundo arreglo que contiene: el nombre
del color y el significado de cada uno, en caso de encontrarlo, es necesario
escribir en una última columna de la Tabla 1 el significado del color, de lo
contrario debe escribir la frase “No se encuentra el significado”.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor

Comment: podes usar [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) + [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) como en este ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/259182/81450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy fácil, existe la función in_array que comprueba si un valor existe en un array, el código sería algo así

```
$colores = ['Amarillo','Verde','Rojo'];
$colorAbuscar = 'Verde';

if(in_array($colorAbuscar, $colores))
    echo 'Color encontrado';
else
    echo 'color no encontrado';
```

Te dejo la liga de la función, por si tienes dudas : https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Otra forma seria, en el array de colores solo pongas los colores con significado y pongas además el nombre del color como índice. De este otro modo tienes que usar la función array_key_exists que verifica si existe el índice en un array y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$colores = ['Amarillo'=>'Riqueza y alegria','Verde'=>'Tranquilizante, Equilibrado y Funcional'];
$colorAbuscar = 'Amarillo';

if(array_key_exists($colorAbuscar,$colores))
    echo $colorAbuscar.':'.$colores[$colorAbuscar];
else
    echo $colorAbuscar.': No se encuentra el significado';
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Manuel me sirvio de mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes conseguirlo mediante la query:

```sql
SELECT p.nombre, p.direccion, p.telefono, p.fecha_nacimiento, p.color_favorito, COALESCE(c.significado, 'No se encuentra el significado') 
FROM personas p 
LEFT JOIN colores c on p.color_favorito = c.color;
```